# Are there languages that support Multiple Inheritance of two or more Classes?

Tags: java, php, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I know that PHP and Java don't allow to do that. I guess that other languages don't allow to do like that too. But why? I think that it would be quite useful.

Here's code (it's not correct syntax for any language) that explains what I meant...

```
class X extends Y, Z {

}
```

If it would be possible, class X would have all fields and methods that Y and Z have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C++ allows multiple inheritance.

You can read a full description of this feature [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.23.4735%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=_1S5TfjtDIuCtgf1nLXeBA&usg=AFQjCNGTrsxMLC4tSP9OuZWF2bCuFXmuHQ&sig2=u_XPXhZTR9ePAmyZhDOsMA) in an article by Bjarne Stroustrup, the creator of C++.

But it's not the silver bullet to all of your problems. Multiple inheritance generally creates more problems than it solves. Perhaps you could get better suggestions if you posted a question explaining what you were trying to achieve in the language of your choice?

I certainly would not suggest learning C++ just to take advantage of multiple inheritance.

Comment: I don't have any specific problem right now. I just thought that it would be useful... sometimes. Can you explain what did you meant with "more problems"?

Comment: @daGrevis: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem is the classic answer. But beyond that, things just start getting complicated with that much inheritance going on. 9 times out of 10, there's a better solution that does not involve multiple inheritance. In languages like C#, the executive decision was made that the feature is more complicated to implement than it is generally useful, and thus it was omitted from the language entirely. Empirical evidence indicates that few programmers miss it.

Comment: that link is no longer loading. for me, at least

Answer (score 13):

**Multiple inheritance is supported by following languages :**

Perl, Perl 6, Python, C++, Curl, Dylan, Eiffel, Logtalk, Object REXX, OCaml,and Tcl
**Also** Scala (**via** use of mixin classes) and PHP (**via** use of traits classes)

**and good to know**

Some languages, such as C#, Java, and Ruby implement *single inheritance* although protocols, or interfaces, provide some of the functionality of true multiple inheritance.

Comment: Best and most complete answer imo.

Answer (score 2):

C++?

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/117-multiple-inheritance/

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to refer to Wikipedia, as there's a list of programming languages which support multiple inheritance in the way you expect, or as the mechanism called "mixin".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you having two properties/methods with same names in both Y and Z classes, so compiler doesn't know from what class property/method must be inherited. 
*In Java you can use Interfaces for multiple inheritance.

Comment: I thought that it would be logic, that X inherits first from Y. Then from Z. Z is like higher than Y, because it's after Y. So if both (Y and Z) have, for example, the same methods, finally, X would have Z method.

Comment: @daGrevis: Hmm, that's an interesting approach. In the languages that I'm familiar with (C++), there isn't a concept of "ordering" when it comes to inheritance. However, it appears that what you describe is exactly how Perl handles this, requiring that you specify the inheritance classes in an ordered list. To my mind, that's a strange model, but there are many possible ways of solving the Diamond problem.

Comment: Funny. I think that is so logic as it can be. =D Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Python:

```
class DerivedClassName(Base1, Base2, Base3):
<statement-1>
.
.
.
<statement-N>
```

See the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html) 9.5.1. Multiple Inheritance

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve multiple inheritance in Java with interface default methods. It's not perfect but works most of the time.